# Unable to link created .so file to main.cpp

Tags: c++, ubuntu, shared-libraries

Good day! I am running a c++ project main.cpp in eclipse. i want to use my existing .so file and link it in main.cpp. I am searching about this but cant find the right method for me. I'm using ubuntu. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

To link against a library you need to supply the compiler(or the linker) a `-l` flag and the library name. For example, if you want to link against a library called *libjustine.so*, you would supply your compiler(gcc if C, g++ if C++) a flag `-ljustine` and then the compiler would instruct the linker to link against a file *libjustine.so* in the library path (usually at least */usr/lib/* and */usr/local/lib/*).

However, if you want to define your own library directory, for example a *lib/* directory inside your project directory, you need to use the `-L` flag and supply the desired library  directory(relative to the current directory) that way, for example `-L/lib/` so the compiler can instruct the linker to look for the desired library from *lib/* instead of for example */usr/lib/* where it looks for the file by default.

Comment: can you pls give me an example code to do this? for example i want to link libjustinte.so to main.cpp. is libjustine.so needed to be installed or you just need to put it in /usr/lib or /usr/local/lib? thanks for your answer!

Comment: I am not aware how you define linker options in Eclipse so I can't give direct answer to your problem that way. But yes, you need to have the file *libjustinte.so* in so-called library path. This *usualy* includes both /usr/lib and /usr/local/lib for example, so both should work. As I mentioned in the answer, you can also supply your C or C++ compiler(gcc/g++) with the `-L` flag to define the path to the library, relative to the current directory.

Comment: What if I had something like libv8.so.3.8.9.20? It doesn't seem to work... :(